# Date field in mysql not updating from php/html form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, date, post

I have this html form intended to update values in a MySQL database. On page load the table gets populated with existing data from the database.
When I issue the POST command, all the fields in the database gets updated except for DATE. What am I doing wrong here?

The MySQL table:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|# | Name       | Type         | Collation       | Null | Default     | Extra    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1 | ID         | int(11)      |                 | No   | none        | auto_inc |
|2 | username   | varchar(50)  | utf8_general_ci | No   | none        |          |
|3 | date       | date         |                 | No   | none        |          |
|4 | mission    | varchar(100) | utf8_general_ci | No   | none        |          |
|5 | transFrom  | varchar(100) | utf8_general_ci | No   | none        |          |
|6 | transpTo   | varchar(100) | utf8_general_ci | No   | none        |          |
|7 | payment    | varchar(100) | utf8_general_ci | No   | none        |          |
|8 | comment    | text         | utf8_general_ci | No   | none        |          |
|9 | created_at | datetime     |                 | Yes  | curnt_tstmp |          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The form:

```
<?php
 require_once("db.php");
 $arr = $conn->getMissionsId();
 $mission_id = isset($_GET['id']) ?  $_GET['id'] : '';

for($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
  if ($id = $mission_id && $arr[$i]['username'] == $_SESSION['username']) {
      $username = $arr[$i]['username'];
      $date = $arr[$i]['date'];
      $mission = $arr[$i]['mission'];
      $from = $arr[$i]['transpFrom'];
      $to = $arr[$i]['transpTo'];
      $payment = $arr[$i]['payment'];
      $comment = $arr[$i]['comment'];
  }
}

?>
<div class='newMissionForm'>
<form method='POST' action='?p=editMissionUpdate' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class='masterHeading'>Oppdater oppdrag</div>
<input type='hidden' name='id' id='id' class='inputClass' value='<?php echo $id ?>'>
<div class='form1'><label for='date' class='labelClass'>Dato</label><input type='date' name='date' id='date' class='inputClass' value='<?php echo $date ?>'></div>
<div class='form1'><label for='mission' class='labelClass'>Type oppdrag</label>
  <select class='form_control inputClass' id='mission' name='mission'>
    <option value=''>Velg oppdragstype</option>
    <option value='Vakt hverdag'<?php if ($mission == "Vakt hverdag") echo " selected='selected'"; ?>>Vakt hverdag</option>
    <option value='Vakt helg'<?php if ($mission == "Vakt helg") echo " selected='selected'"; ?>>Vakt helg</option>
    <option value='Vakt helgedag'<?php if ($mission == "Vakt helgedag") echo " selected='selected'"; ?>>Vakt helgedag</option>
    <option value='Vakt hel uke'<?php if ($mission == "Vakt hel uke") echo " selected='selected'"; ?>>Vakt hel uke</option>
    <option value='Vakt firedagers uke'<?php if ($mission == "Vakt firedagers uke") echo " selected='selected'"; ?>>Vakt firedagers uke</option>
    <option value='Tillegg helgedag'<?php if ($mission == "Tillegg helgedag") echo " selected='selected'"; ?>>Tillegg helgedag</option>
  </select>
  <div id='missionInfo1' class='<?php if ($mission !== 'Vakt hverdag') { echo ' none'; } ?> missionInfo'><?php infoVaktHverdag() ?></div>
  <div id='missionInfo2' class='<?php if ($mission !== 'Vakt helg') { echo ' none'; } ?> missionInfo'><?php infoVaktHelg() ?></div>
  <div id='missionInfo3' class='<?php if ($mission !== 'Vakt helgedag') { echo ' none'; } ?> missionInfo'><?php infoVaktHelgedag() ?></div>
  <div id='missionInfo4' class='<?php if ($mission !== 'Vakt hel uke') { echo ' none'; } ?> missionInfo'><?php infoVaktUke() ?></div>
  <div id='missionInfo5' class='<?php if ($mission !== 'Vakt firedagers uke') { echo ' none'; } ?> missionInfo'><?php infoVakt4dgUke() ?></div>
  <div id='missionInfo6' class='<?php if ($mission !== 'Tillegg helgedag') { echo ' none'; } ?> missionInfo'><?php infoTilleggHelg() ?></div>
</div>
<div class='form1'><label for='from' class='labelClass'>Transport fra</label><input type='text' name='from' id='from' class='inputClass' value='<?php echo $from ?>'></div>
<div class='form1'><label for='to' class='labelClass'>Transport til</label><input type='text' name='to' id='to' class='inputClass' value='<?php echo $to ?>'></div>
<div class='form1'><label for='payment' class='labelClass'>Lønn</label><input type='text' name='payment' id='payment' class='inputClass readonly' value='<?php echo $payment ?>' readonly></div>
<div class='form1'><label for='comment' class='labelClass'>Kommentar</label>
  <textarea name='comment' id='comment' class='inputClass2'><?php echo $comment ?></textarea></div>

<button type="submit" name="submit_form" class="btn btn-primary">Oppdater oppdrag</button>
</form>
<?php btnCancel(); ?>
</div>
```

The function `getMIssionsID()`:

```
 public function getMissionsId()
 {
     $arr = array();
     $mission_id = isset($_GET['id']) ?  $_GET['id'] : '';
     $statement = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, username, date, mission, transpFrom, transpTo, payment, comment, created_at from missions where id = $mission_id");
     //echo $this->conn->error;
     $statement->bind_result($id, $username, $date, $mission, $from, $to, $payment, $comment, $created_at);
     $statement->execute();
     while ($statement->fetch()) {
       $arr[] = [ "id" => $id, "username" => $username, "date" => $date, "mission" => $mission, "transpFrom" => $from, "transpTo" => $to, "payment" => $payment,
       "comment" => $comment, "created_at" => $created_at];
     }
     $statement->close();

     return $arr;
 }
```

The file that gets called when issuing POST command (editMissionUpdate.php):

```
<?php
require_once("db.php");

 $id = intval($_POST['id']);
 $mission = strip_tags($_POST['mission']);
 $rawdate = htmlentities($_POST['date']);
 $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rawdate));
 $from = strip_tags($_POST['from']);
 $to = strip_tags($_POST['to']);
 $payment = strip_tags($_POST['payment']);
 $comment = strip_tags($_POST['comment']);

 $conn->updateMission($id, $mission, $date, $from, $to, $payment, $comment);
?>

<div style='width: 50em'>
<div class='masterHeading'>Oppdraget er oppdatert</div>
  <br><br>
  <div class='descrText'>Oppdraget ble vellykket oppdatert.</div>
<?php btnCancel(); ?>
</div>
```

The function `updateMission()`:

```
 public function updateMission($id, $mission, $date, $from, $to, $payment, $comment)
 {
     $statement = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE missions SET mission = ?,date = ?,transpFrom = ?,transpTo = ?,payment = ?,comment = ? WHERE id = ?");
     echo $this->conn->error;
     $statement->bind_param('ssssssi', $mission, $date, $from, $to, $payment, $comment, $id);
     $statement->execute();
     $statement->close();

 }
```

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, but I don't like your `getMissionsId()` method. It gets an array instead of an identifier. So the name doesn't match its function. Moreso it relies on the presence of `$_GET['id']`, which is the identifier in question. So it doesn't even 'get' it, it needs it. I would use a parameter instead of the super global `$_GET`, and name the method `getMissionRow($missionId);`.

Comment: Thank you! Should I pass the parameter using `$_SESSION`?

Comment: I cannot answer that question, it would require me to understand your code completely, and I don't. Just don't use the super global `$_GET` inside a method of a class. "Why?"; you ask? For one, it means you can use the method independent of any url query parameter. Also, a method should do one thing. Adding the retrieval and validation of a query parameter to it, just confuses things. There are fancy terms for this, but just remember that a method's name should reflect what it does, and it should only do one clearly defined thing.

Comment: Another way to think about this is: If you cannot give a short and clear name to a method, that **exactly** describes what it does, then you're probably doing it wrong. You either do too much in one method, or, and this is worse, don't really know what's going on inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change $id = $mission_id by  $id = $arr[$i]['id'] to solve the problem :)

Comment: Thank you, but I am unable to spot the 8th parameter in `$statement->bind_param`. Could you elaborate?

Comment: $statement->bind_param('ssssssi', $mission, $date, $from, $to, $payment, $comment, $id);
1 = 'ssssssi'
2 = $mission
3 = $date
4 =  $from
5 = $to
6 = $payment
7 = $comment
8 =  $id
I suggest you print the SQL statement to debug

Comment: Please print the SQL statement after bind_param

Comment: Ah, thanks! The purpose of the first parameter here (`ssssssi`) is to bind the other variables and define the ID. Or am I wrong? Removing this parameter gives me the folowing error: `Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables`. How would I print the statement? `echo $statement;`?

Comment: Sorry, i understand about "ssssssi" now. Please print SQL statement to debug

Comment: How do I print the SQL statement? `echo $statement;` and `print $statement;` gives me the following error. `Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_stmt could not be converted to string`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176542/discussion-between-thorbj-and-mage-wet).